# Splitting string containing spaces in C# Regex

Tags: c#, regex, string, datagridview, spaces

For example I have this string:
BTW This is a comment "hahaha"

BTW is a comment operator and all statements after it are ignored.
I need to put BTW as 'comment_operator' and 'This is a comment "hahaha"' as 'comment' in a datagridview.

But I can't do it because I used space as a delimiter in my code, so 'This is a comment "hahaha"' will be concatenated too but I need it as it is.

Can someone enlighten me with this? Thanks.

Comment: Post some code please! It will make it easier to understand your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the separate 2 parts by the first occurrence of space. You can use the code below:

```
string text = @"BTW This is a comment ""hahaha""";
string comment_operator = text.Substring(0, text.IndexOf(' '));
string comment = text.Substring(comment_operator.Length + 1);
```